# "incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘strcpy’" error in C

Tags: c, string, struct, strtok

I am writing a program where I must define my own versions of the following functions:

```
int AtoI ( const char * str );
int StrCmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
char * StrCpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
char * StrCat ( char * destination, const char * source );
char * StrChr ( char * str, int character );
```

Inside the main function, I am required to declare an array called wordlist of type myWord of size 20. Then, using the strtok() library function, extract each word from the string MyString and store it in wordlist. However, I keep getting the error message:

```
incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘strcpy’
```

for the line:

```
strcpy(wordlist[i], token);
```

How do I fix this problem? So far, this is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myWord{
    char word[21];
    int length;
};

int main(void){
    typedef struct myWord myword;
    int i = 0;
    myword wordlist[20];
    char *myString = "the cat in the hat jumped over the lazy fox";

    char *token;
    token = strtok(myString, " ");

    while(myString != NULL){
        strcpy(wordlist[i], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("%s\n", wordlist[i]);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Comment: `wordlist[i]` --> `wordlist[i].word`

Comment: Also `char *myString` --> `char myString[]` and `myString != NULL` --> `token != NULL`

Comment: I made the corrections, and it works for the most part, but after printing all the tokens, it gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", wordlist[i]);` ---> `printf("%s\n", wordlist[i].word);`

Comment: `while(myString != NULL)` --> `while(token != NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct myWord{
    char word[21];
    int length;
}myword;

int main(void){
    int i = 0;
    myword wordlist[20];
    char myString[] = "the cat in the hat jumped over the lazy fox";

    char *token;
    token = strtok(myString, " ");

    while(token != NULL){
        strcpy(wordlist[i].word, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("%s\n", wordlist[i].word);
        i++;
    }    
}
```

1. C-string member of your struct is `word`, so you must pass that member to `strcpy` and `printf`
2. Your loop must check `token`  returned by `strtok` to check if the end of string was reached
3. `strtok` modify your string to do the job, so the string must be modifiable, you cannot use a pointer to a string literal.